# Randomizing a list of zeros and ones with constraints

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, shuffle

I'm currently trying to randomize a list of 0s and 1s which should give a random order of zeros and ones with the following constraints:

1. 1/3 of the items have to be 1s (respectively 2/3 are 0s)
2. No more than two 1s should occur consecutively
3. No more than four zeros should occur consecutively

I have worked on an option, but it did not exactly turn out to be what I need. Here's my option:

```
for prevItem, nextItem in enumerate(WordV[: -1]):
            if nextItem  == WordV[prevItem+1] and WordV[prevItem+1] == WordV[prevItem+2] and nextItem ==1: 
                WordV[prevItem+2] = 0
            if nextItem  == WordV[prevItem+1] and WordV[prevItem+1] == WordV[prevItem+2] and WordV[prevItem+2] == WordV[prevItem+3] and WordV[prevItem+3] == WordV[prevItem+4] and nextItem == 0: 
                WordV[prevItem+2] = 1

# Check the number of ones & zeros
print(WordV)
ones= WordV.count(1)
zeros= WordV.count(0)
print(ones, zeros)
```

Currently, the number of ones and zeros does not add up to a proportion of 1/3 to 2/3 because the constraints replace numbers. The WordV list is a list containing 24 ones and 48 zeros that is shuffled randomly (with random.shuffle(WordV)).

Is there a smarter (and more correct) way to integrate the constraints into the code?

Comment: Does it need to be fast?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

def consecutive(data, stepsize=0):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

def check(list_to_check):
    groups = consecutive(list_to_check)
    for group in groups:
        if group[0] == 1 and group.size > 2:
            return True
        if group[0] == 0 and group.size > 4:
            return True

wordv = np.array([1]*24+[0]*48)


while check(wordv):
    np.random.shuffle(wordv)
```

wordv will contain something like:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

The consecutive function will split the data in groups containing the same element:

```
[ins] In [32]: consecutive([1,1,1,0,0,1])
Out[32]: [array([1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0]), array([1])]
```

The check will check both conditions you specified and we will shuffle the list until we meet the conditions

Comment: If you just re-shuffle the entire list until you get a "good" one this might take extremely long if the list is a bit longer and the constraints are somewhat "tight".

Comment: The requirement is that it would be a random list with requirements, so yeah true. A genetic algorithm might find a solution as well, but that seems overkill here. Every smart way to do it will be too deterministic to call it a random enough.

Comment: For short lists, where this appraoch is feasible, this might in fact be more random, but for longer lists, it just does not work, e.g. with 200 0s and 100 1s. This _might_ not be a problem, just saying.

Comment: If I find the time, I'll check for the genetic algorithm approach, which still should return a random result, but might per definition not always find one.

Answer (score 1):

You could try an optimization approach: Start with the list holding the elements in the right proportion, then keep swapping random elements until you get the desired results. In each turn, check the number of too-long streaks of 0s or 1s and always keep the better one of the original or the mutated list.

```
import itertools, random

def penalty(lst):
    return sum(1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst)
               if k == 0 and len(list(g)) > 4 or k == 1 and len(list(g)) > 2)

def constrained_shuffle(lst):
    # penalty of original list
    p = penalty(lst)
    while p > 0:
        # randomly swap two elements, get new penalty
        a, b = random.randrange(len(lst)), random.randrange(len(lst))
        lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]
        p2 = penalty(lst)
        if p2 > p:
            # worse than before, swap back
            lst[a], lst[b] = lst[b], lst[a]
        else:
            p = p2

lst = [0] * 20 + [1] * 10
random.shuffle(lst)
constrained_shuffle(lst)
print(lst)
```

For 200 0s and 100 1s this will take a few hundred to a few thousand iterations until it finds a valid list, which is okay. For lists with thousands of elements this is rather too slow, but could probably be improved by memorizing the positions of the too-long streaks and preferrably swapping elements within those.

---

About the "randomness" of the approach: Of course, it is less random than just repeatedly generating a new shuffled list until one fits the constraints, but I don't see how this will create a bias for or against certain lists, as long as those satisfy the constraints. I did a short test, repeatedly generating shuffled lists and counting how often each variant appears:

```
counts = collections.Counter()
for _ in range(10000):
    lst = [0] * 10 + [1] * 5
    random.shuffle(lst)
    constrained_shuffle(lst)
    counts[tuple(lst)] += 1
print(collections.Counter(counts.values()).most_common())
[(7, 197), (6, 168), (8, 158), (9, 157), (5, 150), (10, 98), (4, 92), 
 (11, 81), (12, 49), (3, 49), (13, 43), (14, 23), (2, 20), (15, 10),
 (1, 8), (16, 4), (17, 3), (18, 1)]
```

So, yes, maybe there are a few lists that are more likely than others (one appeared 18 times, three 17 times, and most others 5-9 times). For 100,000 iterations, the "more likely" lists appear ~50% more often than the others, but still only about 120 times out of those 100,000 iterations, so  I'd think that this is not too much of a problem.

Without the initial `random.shuffle(lst)` there are more lists what appear much more often than the average, so this should *not* be skipped.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Why not, care to elaborate? It's starting with a randomly shuffled list and doing entirely random replacements until the constraints are satisfied.

Comment: You say start "sorted or normally shuffled, does not really matter". For starting sorted, I'd expect a bias to remain. For starting shuffled, I don't know, but I could imagine it creates a bias.

Comment: I averaged `sum(i for i, bit in enumerate(lst) if bit)` over 10,000 runs. When starting shuffled, the average is around 145. When starting sorted, it's around 151. Consistently.

Comment: Oh and here's an argument: Unless your initial shuffle happens to be valid (unlikely), your result is only a single swap away from being invalid. So there's a bias towards such "almost invalid" results.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I removed the bit about the initial shuffle being optional. Without shuffling, the lists are still pretty "random", but there is a bias towards particular results.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Okay, that last one _is_ an argument. Guess you could continue doing a few more swaps (that do not invalidate the list again).

Comment: Actually I'm not sure the argument is totally valid as is, since maybe *all* valid lists are only one swap away from invalid (haven't thought that through). But even then I'd suspect some similar bias, like having more possibilities for the single-invalidating-swap.

Comment: Took this as an opportunity to practice pandas. Ran your experiment with 100,000 iterations and also did that with a `while penalty(lst): random.shuffle(lst)` solution. The [comparison of the frequencies](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hf1pLp4V4s4jhUSoc6d6Gnd89gXYRgVc) shows you have stronger/more extremes (outcomes with very high or very low frequency).

Comment: @HeapOverflow Yeah, I also wrote a generator for all valid permutations (no luck truly-randomizing that one, though) and there are indeed some that are never reached. Continuing swapping after a valid combination is found helps a bit, but not much. If you have a better idea, go for it...

Comment: Hmm, how many valid permutations are there? For both solutions I also printed `len(counts)` and both were 1314, so it looked like all valid permutations got reached.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know python, so I'll give you pseudocode:

```
int length;
int[] onesAndZeros = new int[length];

for(int i: onesAndZeros) { // generate a random list
    i = random(0, 1);
}

int zeroCount() { // correct the ratio
    int c;
    for(int i: onesAndZeros) {
        if(i == 0) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int wantedZeros;
if(zeroCount() / (length - zeroCount()) != 2) { // you should probably check a small interval, but this answer is already long
    int a = 2*(length - zeroCount()) - zeroCount(); // I will include the math if necessary
    wantedZeros = zeroCount() + a;
}
while(zeroCount() != wantedZeros) {
    boolean isLess = zeroCount < wantedZeros;
    if(isLess) {
        onesAndZeros[random(0, length - 1)] = 0;
    } else {
        onesAndZeros[random(0, length - 1)] = 0;
    }
}

string isCorrect() { // fix the 2 1s and 4 0s
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(onesAndZeros[i] == 0 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 1] == 0 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 2] == 0 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 3] == 0 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 4] == 0) { // be sure not to go out of bounds!
            return "0" + i;
        } else 
        if(onesAndZeros[i] == 1 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 1] == 1 &&
           onesAndZeros[i + 2] == 1) {
            return "1" + i;
        } else {
            return "a";
        }
    }
}

void fix(int type, int idx) {
    if(type == 0) {
        onesAndZeros[idx + 4] = 1;
    } else {
        onesAndZeros[idx + 2] = 0;
    }
}

string corr = isCorrect();
while(length(corr) >= 2) { // note: this step will screw up the ones/zeros ratio a bit, if you want to restore it, consider running the last 2 steps again
    if(corr[0] == '0') {
        fix(0, toInt(removeFirstChar(corr)));
    } else {
        fix(1, toInt(removeFirstChar(corr)));
    }
}

// done!
```

I'm well aware that this can be greatly optimized and cleaned up, depending on the language. But this is more of a solid base to build upon.